# How do I merge or update dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have an original dataframe as:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_excel("Weights.xlsx", sheet_name='Old')
df: 
     Name  S_Name  Height  Weight
0    John  Wright     5.3      52
1   Seven  Taylor     6.4      75
2  Ramsay     Sen     7.2      77
```

I get a new file with updated / new information every time.
example:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("Weights.xlsx", sheet_name='New')
df1:
     Name   S_Name  Height  Weight
0    John   Wright     5.1      57
1   Seven   Taylor     6.3      76
2  Ramsay      Sen     7.0      71
3   Radio     Mast     5.3      62
4   Randy  Stenson     6.4      65
```

[You can find the file used here](https://gofile.io/d/eFR6nj)

I want to preserve the values of `df` while I add the new rows from `df1` for new `Name` and `S_Name` such that the resulting dataframe is as:

```
df_final
     Name   S_Name  Height  Weight
0    John   Wright     5.3      52
1   Seven   Taylor     6.4      75
2  Ramsay      Sen     7.2      77
3   Radio     Mast     5.3      62
4   Randy   Stenson    6.4      65
```

I would like to add, that the indexes of both files are not the same every time. There is a sort function in the workflow that changes the index position of these values every time.

Comment: It depends, are the two DataFrames aligned on the index?

Comment: Mostly, yes. However there is a sort function in the workflow that does not guarantee that might be the case every time

Comment: Then you should probably merge + update or set_index + combine_first

Comment: Can you please point me to an example that I can follow for this?

Comment: Can you provide your two inputs as DataFrame constructors?

Comment: Sure, so `df` is a `pd.read_csv` and `df1` is imported the same way

Comment: No, I meant your examples, so that I can reproduce them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245137/discussion-between-leonardo-and-mozway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot guarantee that the indices are aligned, you need to use **both** `merge` and `update` (or `combine_first` of you do not want to modify `df1` in place)

You can align the DataFrames with `merge`, then `update`:

```py
ids = ['Name', 'S_Name']
df1.update(df1[ids].merge(df, how='left'))

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
     Name   S_Name  Height  Weight
0    John   Wright     5.3    52.0
1   Seven   Taylor     6.4    75.0
2  Ramsay      Sen     7.2    77.0
3   Radio     Mast     5.3    62.0
4   Randy  Stenson     6.4    65.0
```

If you rather want a new DataFrame:

```py
ids = ['Name', 'S_Name']
df_final = df.combine_first(df1[ids].merge(df, how='left'))

print(df_final)
```

*NB. In both cases, you need to ensure that you have non-duplicated merging keys*

Comment: I am assuming `df1` here is `df` as in my example and `df2` is `df1` and the resulting `df2` is `df_final` as my example. Am I correct?

Comment: No, `update` modifies `df2` in place, I'll update

Comment: I am not able to replicate the same for another dataframe. Should I update the question with the new dataframe to better understand this?

Comment: How are you unable to replicate? Do you have duplicates?

Comment: No, I dont have duplicates. However with the new dataframe is having the new values and not the old ones. I will post my code in a pastebin example if I am doing this right. Doing it now.

Comment: [Pastebin Example](https://pastebin.com/uEHYjgzB)

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: I realized I did not use the same names as you, can you check the update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245141/discussion-between-leonardo-and-mozway).